# Replace a part of an element in a list of strings

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list which contains some strings like below:

```
List<String> l = new List<String>(){
    "item1 1", 
    "item2 2", 
    "item3 3", 
    "item1 4", 
    "item1 5",
    "item3 6"};
```

I would like to sum the items which are the same. Example:

```
l = {"item1 10", "item2 2", "item3 9"}
```

I've tried this:

```
List<String> result = new List<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < total.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
       int diferenta = 0;
       if (total[i].Substring(0, total[i].IndexOf("    ")).Equals(total[j].Substring(0, total[j].IndexOf("   "))))
    {
         diferenta = int.Parse(ExtractNumber(total[i].Substring(total[i].IndexOf("    ")))) + int.Parse(ExtractNumber(total[j].Substring(total[j].IndexOf("    "))));
          total[i] = total[i].Replace(ExtractNumber(total[i].Substring(total[i].IndexOf("    "))), diferenta.ToString());
         result.Add(total[i]);
    }
}
```

And to get the distinct elements:

```
List<String> final = result.Distinct().toList();
```

My way is not correct at all so i want to ask you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split each element, group by the first component, then sum the the second components up:

```
var groupQuery = l.Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ' ' })).GroupBy(x => x[0]);
var sumQuery = groupQuery.Select(x => new { x.Key, Total = x.Select(elem => int.Parse(elem[1])).Sum() });
foreach (var total in sumQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", total.Key, total.Total);
}
```

This code obviously omits a bunch of error checking (what happens if a string doesn't split, or doesn't have a second component that can be parsed?), but that can be added in without too much difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Without handling bad data(for instance not splitted by a white-space etc.).

```
int sumTotal = (from i in l
        let parts = i.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        let id = parts[0]
        let count = int.Parse(parts[1])
        group count by id into Numbers
        where Numbers.Count() != 1
        select Numbers.Sum()).Sum();
```

**Edit**: Haven't seen that you want to count every item even if it has no duplicate. That's even easier, you just need to remove `where CountGroup.Count() != 1` from the query :)

So the complete LINQ query including handling data in wrong format:

```
int number=0;
int sum = (from i in l
          let parts = i.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          where parts.Length==2
          let id = parts[0]
          let isInt = int.TryParse(parts[1], out number)
          where isInt
          group number by id into Numbers
          select Numbers.Sum()).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> outputList =
    inputList.GroupBy(s => s.Split(' ')[0])
             .Select(g.Key + " " + g.Sum(s => int.Parse(s.Split(' ')[1])).ToString());
```

Hooray for LINQ! :)

Note: There is no error trapping, and I am assuming the data is always correct. I have not tested the code for performance or errors.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list. For each item, split on `" "`. Add the prefix (splits[0]) to a map of (String:Integer). If string exists in map, then retrieve its value first, then add current item value (split[1]), then add the sum back to map.

At the end your map will have sum for each string. Just iterate through the map items to output it.